# javascript - clearTimeout for a dynamically created setTimeout

Tags: javascript

In one of my nodejs route , i am trying to start a infinite loop with setTimeout like below,

```
router.post('/start', function(req, res) { 

  var cntr = 0;
  this[req.code+'_'+cntr] = setTimeout(function jobThatRunEveryMinute() {

       // some Expensive Code that may take more than one minute To Run here

       // start another job after someExpensiveCode completes
       setTimeout(jobThatRunEveryMinute, 60000);
  }, 60000);

}
```

This works without any issue. Now i want to stop this in another route request,

```
router.post('/stop', function(req, res) { 
  var cntr = 0;
  clearTimeout(this[req.code+'_'+cntr])
}
```

This stop route is not clearing the timeout and also no error shown. Is there any different way to handle this kind of dynamically created setTimeout ? please suggest something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setTimeout` twice is your problem. Your reference to `setTimeout` is only referencing the outer `setTimeout`, and thus only cancelling the first call (which has probably already been invoked). The **nested** `setTimeout` is not referenced and is not cancelled, so will continue to call `jobThatRunEveryMinute` infinitely.

One solution is to use `setInterval` instead:

```js
router.post('/start', function(req, res) { 

    function jobThatRunEveryMinute(){
        // do whatever...
    }

    jobThatRunEveryMinute() // run straightaway

    // run again in 60 sec, and every 60 sec thereafter, until cancelled
    this[req.code] = setInterval(jobThatRunEveryMinute, 60000)
}
```

Then to cancel:

```js
router.post('/stop', function(req, res) { 
    clearInterval(this[req.code])
}
```

### Update:

Based on OP's comments below, this is actually closer to the partial solution given as part of the question.

```js
router.post('/start', function(req, res) { 

    this[req.code] = null; // clear any previous 'cancelled' state, see below.

    function jobThatRunEveryMinute(){
        // do whatever...

        // run again in 60 sec, and every 60 sec thereafter, until cancelled
        if (this[req.code] !== 'cancelled'){
            this[req.code] = setTimeout(jobThatRunEveryMinute, 60000)
        }
    }

    jobThatRunEveryMinute() // first run
}
```

Then to cancel:

```js
router.post('/stop', function(req, res) { 
    clearTimeout(this[req.code]);
    this[req.code] = 'cancelled'; // needed to track if cancelled while running
}
```

So you were actually quite close. The thing to note is that `this[req.code]` will only keep track of the *next* callback. Every time it's set, it'll get a new reference, which makes sense, as the old one has just completed.

Note: I'd consider not setting a dynamic variable directly on `this`, it has the potential to cause a bug by overriding some other variable. An object map such as `this.timers = {}; this.timers[req.code] = ...;` would be safer.

Comment: Thanks@Richard. But if i change to this[req.code] = setInterval(jobThatRunEveryMinute, 60000), setInterval will not wait for jobThatRunEveryMinute to complete.

Comment: What's the exact behavior you want here? Wait until job 1 has completed, add 60 seconds, then start job 2. Or... Start job 1, set timer, when finished check if there's time remaining before starting job 2. If you clearly define the exact behavior you want I can update my answer.

Comment: I want , Wait until job 1 has completed, add 60 seconds, then start job 2. means 60 seconds gap between two consecutive jobs, irrespective of how long they take to execute.

Comment: Updated twice as I realised it would fail if the cancel request came in while it was running (as opposed to waiting). Not tested, but fairly sure that'll work outta the box.